# A loop that terminates when a certain outcome is reached

Tags: r

I am trying to sample from a sequence from 0 to 36. But i want the loop to terminate if 0 is sampled. This is what i have done so far and it does not work,

```
x <- seq ( 0, 36, by=1 )
for ( i in 1:100) {
x<- sample (x, 1, replace = F, prob=NULL)
if (x[i] == 0){
break
}
print("x[i]")
}
```

Thanks, Pilara

Comment: hi, i dont understand

Answer (score 1):

You have to store all the outcomes of your sampling process in a vector. You could do it like this:

```
set.seed(12345)                 # Set seed to make results reproducible. 
                                # Change the seed for different random numbers
x <- seq(0, 36, by = 1)
y <- sample(x, 1)               # Initialize vector of sampling results
while (tail(y, 1) != 0){
    y <- c(y, sample(x, 1))     # Append results to vector  
}
> y
#  [1] 26 32 28 32 16  6 12 18 26 36  1  5 27  0
```

Comment: Growing an object may be detrimental to performance if N gets large-ish.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik That's true. As there is no natural upper bound for the number of trials (theoretically, it could take any number of trials before you sampled a 0) you would have to set an upper bound yourself ("I am only interested in runs that take x trials or fewer") and initialize the vector y beforehand. You could do that. If you set your max size sufficiently high you probably wouldn't have any problems.

Comment: That, or pre-allocate a vector and expand it on demand. If I recall correctly, this is discussed in Patrick Burns' [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm just tweaking your code a little bit. Just use another variable for storage.

```
x <- seq ( 0, 36, by=1 )
y <- c()
for ( i in 1:100) {
    y[i]<- sample (x, 1, replace = F, prob=NULL)
    if (y[i] == 0){
       break
     }
print(y[i])
}
```

Hope this helps.